# Asymptotic elements of a sequence of of gaps given the average asymptotic function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, prime-gaps

If the average consecutive difference of a sequence of numbers is asymptotically the same as $f(n)$.  Then what can be said about numbers in the sequence, asymptotically as $n \to \infty$.  Let $\Delta a_k = a_k - a_{k-1}$.  Can it be said that 
$\dfrac{\# \{\Delta  a_k :\Delta a_k \lt f(n), \ k= 2 \dots n\}}{\# \{ \Delta a_n: \Delta a_n \gt f(n), \ k =2 \dots n\}} \to 1$ or just some constant or not even a constant?

Also, given this asymptotic information, can we say something about *odd* prime gaps?   Since if $a_k$ were the average consecutive *odd* prime gap, then aymptotically there must be a large enough number of prime gaps less than $f(n) = \log n$ to compensate for the denominator in the limit above.

Is there not enough information, such as bounds on $\Delta a_n$?

The average of the consecutive gaps is just $\dfrac{a_n - a_2}{n-2} \sim \dfrac{a_n - a_2}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum (a_n - a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + \dots + (a_3 - a_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average of the differences $\Delta a_k = a_k - a_{k-1}$ for $k = 1 \ldots N$ is just $(a_N - a_0)/N$.  This is asymptotic to $f(N)$ iff $a_N \sim N f(N)$ as $N \to \infty$.  Let $b_n = a_n/n$.  For $n > 1$, the gap $\Delta a_n < b_n$ iff $b_n < b_{n-1}$.  The asymptotic density of $n$ for which this is true could be anywhere from $0$ to $1$, inclusive, or undefined.

Comment: Do you mean "is just (a_N - a_0)/N"?

Comment: Oops, yes (edited).  Thanks for catching the typo.